# Regular expression for replacing

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans

I`m very weak at regular expressions and i need your help.
The result that i want to accomplish is to replace all

```
$variable
```

in my templates with where "$variable" is a random named php variable

```
$view->escape($variable, 'js')
```

Can someone help me with the regular expression for this.
If you assist me with this by using the search and replace of netbeans it would be more than perfect.
Thanks.

Comment: You don't need a regexp at all for this task

Comment: $variable isn`t constant, i wanted to say i want to replace all variables in my templates(they`re not named variable)

Comment: So, everything, starting from '$' and ending with space should be replaced with $view->escape($variable_name, 'js')? Give better explanation of your task and examples. And you'll get better answers.

Comment: Yes, i modified the explanation and i think it is clear now - "in my templates with where "$variable" is a random named php variable"

Comment: I don't use netbeans. But sed program from Unix is what you need. It can modify source files, based upon regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm ... why you want RegEx for that?

```
str_replace('$variable', '$view->escape($variable, \'js\')', 'YourString');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: This wouldn't work -- since you're using double quotes, PHP will try to use the actual value of the `$variable` -- it isn't defined and hence will generate an error. You want to use single quotes instead.

Comment: Depends on the configuration of the server. Theres an option (i think its the ShortTags option, but im not so sure) which ignores the variables written in doublequotes. But ofc youre right, single quotes would work, ive edited it.^^

Comment: `Depends on the configuration of the server` -- what configuration, exactly? Could you link me to a manual reference?

Comment: Im not completely sure which configuration it is. I just know that on the dev-server in my company the php interpreter ignores if i write something like "Hey my name is $name" - he will output "Hey my name is $name" without using the value of the variable, he treats it like a string. Even in doublequotes.